# Input string that takes in only alphanumeric, # sign and - sign and spaces

Tags: c#, regex, validation

Tried using the following regex code but the - key cant be accepted into my input textbox. Please assist!

My code is as followed:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox_address.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9#- ]+$"))
```

Comment: Looks fine..... http://www.regexper.com/

Comment: @DaveBish thanks for this link! I didn't know that such a tool existed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input string that takes in only letters, alphabets, # and spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562365/input-string-that-takes-in-only-letters-alphabets-and-spaces)

Comment: @Cylian it is not a duplicate. The problem directly comes from how to add "-" in the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the `-` by replacing it by `\-`:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9#\- ]+$
```

As you may see in this expression the `[.-.]` if used to define a set of characters. To explain the regex parser, that your character has not this meaning use `\` to escape it.

It would be the same thing if you want to a regex that matches only numbers and `[`.
To do it : `^[0-9\[]+$` otherwise the regex can't be parsed.

Comment: @CédricBignon: Are you sure this is only how, to include `-` within a `class`?

Comment: You can also avoid escaping `-` by putting it at the end, right next to the closing `]`. And I know at least 1 language that allows `[` to be specified in character class freely (JS), but I prefer escaping them for clarity and portability (Ruby does not allow).